# How do I redirect to another web page from an ASP.NET Controller using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an Angular 1 website with ASP.NET MVC backend. I need a link to gather some parameters using JavaScript, then go to a controller to get the correct URL, then send the user to a different website. However nothing I try is working.

This is the HTML if it matters:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="Link">Some text</a>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
$("#Link").on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location = "/Data/SendToOtherSite?Name=" + $("#nameTextBox").val() + "&Email=" + $("#emailTextBox").val();
    });
```

And this is the method on my controller:

```
public ActionResult SendToOtherSite(string Name, string Email)
        {
            string url = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OtherSiteUrl"] 
                + "/Data/DataFromOldSite?name=" + Name + "&email=" + Email;
            return Redirect(url);
        }
```

I have a breakpoint on SendToOtherSite() but it is never hit and I do not get taken to the new website. What do I need to do?

Comment: *"I have a breakpoint on SendToOtherSite() but it is never hit"* - What about debugging the JavaScript code in the browser?  Is this `click` handler ever invoked?  Are there any errors at all on the browser's development console?  *"I am working on an Angular 1 website"* - And you're also using jQuery?  That seems like a potentially failing mix.  If the intent is to use Angular, why not use Angular?

Comment: There should be some errors listed on Console ( f12- Dev tools). Please post that data if available.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$("#Link").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("SendToOtherSite", "Data")?name=' + $("#nameTextBox").val() + '&email=' + $("#emailTextBox").val();
});
```

The action method parameters should be properly formatted to be able correctly parsed by the MVC standard binding process. Therefore, the [`@Url.Action()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) should be used to build the correct route.

Comment: Same result, thanks anyway,

Comment: @Joe: Is this click handler ever invoked? Do you see any errors in the developer console?